# 400 Error code response for GET api call which has bearer token as authorisation while doing rest assured api automation

Tags: api, rest-assured, bearer-token

Im trying rest assured java api automation. Im using Bearer token authorisation. Im getting 400 as response. Please guide me to get success response

Code:

```
        Map<String, String> headerMap1 = getHeaders();
        Response response = given().headers(headerMap1).auth().oauth2(StepDefition_glue.key).get("https://test.sit1.api.com.au/exp/customer/explore/business");
        ca.getLogger().always().log("test case attachment Response Body is =>  " + response); 
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();   
        ca.getLogger().always().log("The test case attachment status code recieved: " + statusCode);
```

Comment: You have to check your server logs. `400` means that the server decided that you built your request in unexpected way. The particular criteria are up to the server.

Comment: logs are not getting captured while executing automation api code

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting 401 or 400?
Since this is GET request, 400 status code does not make a lof ot sense unless you are not sending any query params as well.

Comment: Im getting 400 error code. Not sending any query params. As part of request im sending bearer token as part of authorization and header also. will this cause any problem for response?

Comment: Its very hard to say exactly without seeing the request that is sent. May be some of the headers is wrong.